# search pattern and delete the next line after pattern from 2nd occurrence using SED

Tags: sed

Am new to Shell scripting and need your help in finding a way to "search a pattern and delete the next line after the pattern from the 2nd occurrence using SED". i was able to delete the line after the search pattern (form 1st occurrence) but my requirement needs to be deleting the empty line after the 2nd occurrence.

```
sed -re "s/^([^^L])/ \1/" -e "s/^^L/1/" -e "/$esc_filename/{p;s/$esc_filename/"${new_filename}"/}" -e "/^"$new_filename"/{n;d}" "$i" >> "$source_dir/${cap_new_rep_id}.TXT"
```

OR

```
sed -re "s/^([^^L])/ \1/" -e "s/^^L/1/" -e "/^ $esc_filename/{p;s/$esc_filename .*/"${cap_new_rep_id}"/}" -e "/"${cap_new_rep_id}"/{N;s/\n.*//;}" "$i" >> "$source_dir/${cap_new_rep_id}.TXT"
```

The above command does search for Control-L and if found replaces with 1 else with a empty space and again search for a string and replace with another string and finally the latest string would be searched and delete the next line after that but i just need an option to delete the next line after the 2nd pattern is found.

It would be great if any one could throw some light in achieving this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: gave us an output of the text to be changed and what you expect your output to be.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `awk` instead:

```
awk -v first=1 '
  !ignore { print }           # unless the line is ignored, print it
  ignore { ignore = 0 }       # if it was ignored, reset ignore flag
  /pattern/ {
    if(!first) { ignore = 1 } # set ignore bit it pattern is found and it is not the first time
    first = 0                 # since the pattern has been found, it is not the first time after this.
  }' foo.txt
```

transforms this file:

```
 0
 pattern
 1
 2
 3
 pattern
 4
 pattern
 6
 7
```

into this:

```
0
pattern
1
2
3
pattern
pattern
7
```

just replace pattern with your pattern, and that should be it. Also, it's much easier to see what is happening than with sed.

EDIT: I should not try to use `'` in comments in a shell script string with single quotes. That was silly.

Addendum: Since OP asked in the comments, one way to delete the Nth line after all but the first appearance of a pattern is by using an ignore counter instead of a flag:

```
# adjust N as necessary
awk -v first=1 -v ignore=0 -v N=2 '
  ignore != 1 { print }          
  ignore != 0 { ignore -= 1 }
  /pattern/ {
    if(!first) { ignore = N }
    first = 0                
  }' foo.txt
```

...and I believe this is the point where I leave a link to an [awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick turn around. the reason why am requesting for a SED command is that i do not want to read the out file again and apply the AWK instead use the SED command to make it in one go. trust you understand.

Comment: You can pipe through awk just the same way you would with sed. Just don't specify a file name and it will read from stdin.

Comment: Thanks Winter, i have achieved the task for which i have posted this request. i modified my script and added the AWK with a pipe and written it back to the output file.

Modified Script:
===============
sed -re "s/^([^^L])/ \1/" -e "s/^^L/1/" -e "/^ $esc_filename/{p;s/$esc_filename .*/"${cap_new_rep_id}"/}" "$i" | awk -v first=1 "!ignore { print } ignore { ignore = 0 } /"$cap_new_rep_id"/ { if(!first) { ignore = 1 } first = 0 }" >> "$source_dir/${cap_new_rep_id}.TXT"

Comment: Hi Winter, Is there an option to delete 2nd or 3rd line other than the next line or the 1st line ?

Comment: Sure. Added an example and an important link.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '0,/pattern/!{/pattern/{N
s/\n.*//g}}'
```

example a file containing the following

```
hello world
I DON'T want to delete this line since the first pattern is above
world
I want to delete this line
my name is John
my name is Joe
world
I want to delete this line
My name is Jack
this is world
I want to delete this line
rule
```

In this case let us consider the pattern is `world`

```
   sed '0,/world/!{/world/{N
    s/\n.*//g}}' my_file
```

Output

```
hello world
I DON'T want to delete this line since the first pattern is above
world
my name is John
my name is Joe
world
My name is Jack
this is world
rule
```